# How to concatenate a string with original & change values from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array with original value and changed value like this:

```
$arr = [
    'first_name' => [
        'original' => 'Rahul',
        'changes' => 'Manan'
    ],
    'last_name' => [
        'original' => 'Shah',
        'changes' => 'Patel'
    ],
    'email_address' => [
        'original' => 'rahul@yahoo.com',
        'changes' => 'manan@gmail.com'
    ]
];
```

Now I want to concatenate a string with the main array key name along with original & changes value like this:

```
$str = 'first_name Rahul => Manan, last_name Shah => Patel, email_address rahul@yahoo.com => manan@gmail.com';
```

Any idea how to do this thing with loop?

Comment: This looks like a pretty basic loop. Did you make any attempt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a foreach and string concat

```
$str ='';
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){

  $str .= ($str == '' ? 
        $key .' ' . $value['original']  .' => ' . $value['changes'] 
      : ', '.  $key .' ' . $value['original']  .' => ' . $value['changes']  );

}
```